# Android migration issues on MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.7 version

Tags: marketing-cloud, android

so I have this problem after updating MarketingCloudSDK to 8.0.7 version, I can't find a way with SFMCSdk to use: `MarketingCloudSdk.isReady()`
Is there a way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice catch. That's missing from the current API, however, what you need can be accomplished with the following ...

```
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.mp {
        // It's "ready" here
    }
}
```